# Multiple linked list with SQLAlchemy and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, linked-list

I want to have multiple linked list in a SQL table, using MySQL and SQLAlchemy (0.7). All lists with it's first node with parent being 0, and ends with child being 0. The id represents the list, and not the indevidiual element. The element is identified by PK

With some omitted syntax (not relevant to the problem) it should look something like this:

```
id(INT, PK)
content (TEXT)
parent(INT, FK(id), PK)
child(INT, FK(id), PK)
```

As the table has multiple linked lists how can return the entire list from the database I select a specific ID and parent is 0?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE id = 3 AND parent = 0
```

Comment: I don't understand. Is `id` the unique identifier of one particular linked list, or of one particular element? And what would you like to extract: All elements of a list? Or all elements of a list _in the correct order_?

Comment: The is is unique to the element, I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: In retrospecr; that was a bad idea so the ID identities the entire list.

Comment: Right, and then extracting the entire list is trivial, isn't it? You just do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 3;`, no? That would give you the elements in random order. Putting them in order would be more difficult, though. I guess it would involve issuing one SQL query for every element, each time setting `id` to whatever the `child` field of the previous element contained.

Comment: You raise a good point, I could `SELECT * FROM table WHERE...` put it in a dict and traverse it sort of recursively. Then the order of the items wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have multiple linked lists stored in the same table, I assume that you store either the HEAD and/or the TAIL of those in some other tables. Few ideas:

**1) Keep the linked list:**
The first big improvement (also proposed in the comments) from the data-querying perspective would be to have some common identifier (lets call it `ListID`) of all the nodes in the same list. Here there are few options:

- If each list is referenced only from **one** object (data row) [I would even phrase the question like "Does the list **belong** to a single object?], then this `ListID` could simply be the (primary) identifier of the holder object with the `ForeignKey` on top to ensure data integrity.
  In this case, querying all list is very simple. In fact, you can define the `relationship` and navigate it like `my_object.my_list_items`.
- If the list is used/referenced by multiple objects, then one could create another table which will consist only of one column `ListID (PK)`, and each Node/Item will again have a ForeignKey to it, or something similar
- Else, large lists can be loaded in two queries/SQL statements:

  1. query the HEAD/TAIL by its ID
  2. query the whole list based on received `ListID` of the HEAD/TAIL
     In fact, this can be done with one query like the one below (*Single-query example*), which is more efficient from the IO perspective, but doing it in two steps has the advantage that you immediately have a reference to the HEAD (or TAIL) node.

*Single-query example:*

```
# single-query using join (not tested)
Head = alias(Node)
qry = session.query(Node).join(Head, Node.ListID == Head.ListID).filter(Head.ID == head_node_id)
```

Iin any case, in order to traverse the linked list, you would have to get the HEAD/TAIL by its ID, then traverse as usual.
*Note: Here I am not certain if SA would recognize that the reference objects are already loaded into session, or will issue other SQL statements for each of these, which will defeat the purpose of bulk loading.*

---

**2) Replace linked list with `Ordering List` extension:**
Please read the [Ordering List](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html) documentation. It well might be that `Ordering List` implementation will be good enough for you to use instead of the linked list

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, after my conversation @jogojapan earlier I changed the the each list element is identified. When it comes to HEADS and TAILS this is 0 which is immutable and in the same table. The way lists are identified is like how you purposed with separate table containing this information that I've called meta. Seems like we've had similar ideas.

Comment: @Chrizmo: do you have a row in this table with the PK=0? Or you do not enforce ForeignKey constraints?

Comment: I enforce ForeignKey constraints and I have PK=0.